# Andengine in android app

Tags: android, andengine

I am using andengine in my android app.
I plan to use animation in my view along with some native widgets embedded in some view.
Is it possible to do it? Can anybody please provide any sample code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can place other Views above AndEngines RenderSurfaceView.

There is even a tutorial on it:
http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/adding-a-view-above-a-game-t498.html

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial link. I will try it out.